# Algolia NOT IN or DOES NOT EQUAL

Tags: javascript, algolia

Is it possible to do a 'NOT IN' syntax. For example:

```
  {"Persons" :[{"Name":"Matthew"},{"Name":"John"}]}
```

Select * from Persons where Name!=John

So essentially select all records that don't have John in Persons.

Comment: `obj.Persons.filter(person => person.Name !== "John")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small note first: you should always use Algolia in conjunction with a database, a search engine will do a poor job on some operations that your database engine should handle.

---

Using Algolia facets exclusion, it's definitely doable:

> Negations are supported via the - operator, prefixing the facet value.
>   For example: `encodeURIComponent('["category:Book","category:-Movie","author:John Doe"]')`

Extract from the documentation of [`facetFilters`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-facetFilters)

---

For your example, assuming "Name" is part of [`attributesForFaceting`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-attributesForFaceting), the query you want to do is simply:

```js
index.search('query', {
  facetFilters: 'Name:-John'
})
```

---

If you're using [`algoliasearch-helper-js`](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js), the method to use is [`addExcludeRefinement`](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/docs/SearchParameters.html#addExcludeRefinement).

---

Finally, it's worth noting that if your attribute was numerical, you should use [`numericFilters`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-numericFilters) instead.

Comment: How would I do it in the instantsearch?  

searchParameters: {
        "disjunctiveFacetsRefinements": {
            //Facet Following Users
            "Email": "-John"

        }

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it would be `searchParameters: { facetsExcludes: { "Persons.Name": ['John'] } }`